# Change the editor for editor form field for a specific view

Tags: joomla, fieldset

I want to change the editor form field only for a specific form in a view to a certain editor, e.g. TinyMCE, but I don't want to change the default editor in the joomla configuration.

Is there a way to specify the editor for a certain editor field?
I found the `hide`  and `editor` attributes for the field [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type), but I can't find an example or more documentation how to use them properly. Are those attributes helpful for my problem at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
editor="tinymce|none"
```

this will give a list of precedence, if tinymce should not be available it will try none.  I guess your editors list can be of any length. Separate editors with pipe "|"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally misinterpreted this notation in the documentation and thought, `desired|none` means, there are only those two options for a value.